# How can i scale up a bounding box in Xna?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

In Xna a spritebatch can be passed a value for scale. I have A bounding
box Rectangle that i have a border drawn around my sprite using the bounding box rect.

Now my question Scale can make the sprite go up just fine,but how
can i get the bounding box rect to scale up with the scale propertie?

Comment: Are you looking to uniformly scale? i.e: the whole box increases by a factor of two around the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust the size of the bounding box to factor in the scale.

i.e.

`Rectangle boundingBox = new Rectangle(texture.Width * scaleX, texture.Height * scaleY)`

`texture` refers to the `Texture2D` instance of your image. `scaleX` and `scaleY` are the horizontal and vertical scaling components respectively, with the trivial case of `scaleX = scaleY` when you scale uniformly.

**Edit:** if the origin of the image is not the default (top-left corner), you should also adjust your rectangle by the origin point.

Comment: This only works if origin is at.. the top left.

Comment: @VaughanHilts updated slightly. The default is the top-left at any rate.

Comment: i still have a problem when I tried this before i posted this question but when I multiply scale * texture scale is a float so when I cast it to a int it gets 1.9999999 .I don't no why this is happening

Comment: @koss If this helped you out, make sure to mark this as the answer.

Comment: @koss float are represented via the equation (Significant digits × base ^ exponent). Unfortunately that can only represent a finite number on values so when you tell it to represent a value that is impossible to represent (2.0) it gives you closest value it can represent (1.999999).

Comment: @koss rounding (up or down, or regular rounding) is usually the solution.

Comment: well i have a new problem . I have a Rectangle((int)position.x,(int)position.y,(int)(width * scale),(int)(height * scale)); I feel  like I might be way off the effect i'm getting is the bounding box orgin seems to be at the sprites orgin position I can't see what to do .it scales perfect but in the wrong spot.

Comment: @koss you need to adjust the X and Y of the bounding box. What's the problem exactly? Can you get a screenshot for us?